# Writing XML In .NET

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlwriter

I am trying to format an XML page in C# per the request of client. Below is what I currently create in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is to write the connection strings, text file location, and report destination.-->
<AdminPaths Name="sqlConnection1" connectionString="asdf">
  <TextPath>
    <Key Value="Test3" xmlns="Path" />
  </TextPath>
</AdminPaths>
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is to write the connection string, text file location, and report destination.-->
<AdminPaths> 
  <Name="sqlConnection1" connectionString="asdf">
</AdminPaths>
<TextPath>
  < Key="Path" Value="Test3">
  < Key="Report" Value="Test2">
</TextPath>
```

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml", settings);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteComment("This is to write the connection strings, text file location, and report destination.");
        writer.WriteStartElement("AdminPaths");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "sqlConnection1");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("connectionString", "asdf");
        writer.WriteStartElement("TextPath");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Key", "Path");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", "Test3");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

I have tried using writer.WriteEndElement(); after the writeAttributeString to start but I receive an error that states "Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment." I believe that is not what I want to do? Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: "What I would like to have" looks like invalid XML...

Comment: What is incorrect about it?

Comment: @BigPoppa xml should have single root element

Comment: @lazyberezovsky by single root element, do you mean i need to only have <adminpaths>?

Comment: The <Key=""/> wont work. You're describing a nameless element with 2 attributes.

Comment: @BigPoppa You have to have single element at the most outer level. So you can't have `<adminpaths>` at the same level as `<textpath>`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : you **can** have `<adminpaths>` at the same level as `<textpath>` if you're prepared to wrap the lot with another element.

Comment: @BigPoppa you still have two root elements. And syntax `<Name="sqlConnection1" connectionString="asdf">` is not correct. You can assign values to attributes, not to elements.

Comment: Ugh. I'll post something to show what might be what you want.

Comment: @spender You're right. I should have specify it a bit more.

Comment: @code4life thank you. thanks everyone for your comments. I've never dealt with XML.

Comment: Note that, in XML terms, this isn't a "format" issue. This is an entirely different XML document that has certain information in common with the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is the XML that you want. I'm guessing, because the XML you state as your goal is not correctly formed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is to write the connection strings, text file location, and report destination.-->
<AdminPaths>
  <AdminPath Name="sqlConnection1" connectionString="asdf" />
  <TextPath>
    <Text Key="Path" Value="Test3" />
    <Text Key="Report" Value="Test2" />
  </TextPath>
</AdminPaths>
```

Basically, in your stated goal XML, you were trying to create 2 root nodes under the xml document, which is a no-no, unless you are willing to use `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` or `ConformanceLevel.Auto` and force this behavior.

The code for this would like the following:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml",
  settings);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteComment("This is to write the connection strings, text file location, and report destination.");

// the AdminPaths
writer.WriteStartElement("AdminPaths");
writer.WriteStartElement("AdminPath");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "sqlConnection1");
writer.WriteAttributeString("connectionString", "asdf");
writer.WriteEndElement();

// the TextPath's
writer.WriteStartElement("TextPath");
writer.WriteStartElement("Text");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Key", "Path");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", "Test3");
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteStartElement("Text");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Key", "Report");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", "Test2");
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement(); // </AdminPaths>
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid XML for reasons like:

- More than one root element, that is a single `<>` element around all of the stuff. In the first example, `<AdminPaths>` is the single root element because everything else is contained within it
- Nodes that don't have no name. For example, `<add=""` is invalid - if the node's name is `add` then it can't have a value directly. Ways to do that is `<add>Value</add>`. Otherwise, you must have an attribute like `<add key="">`
- Similarly, `< Key="Path" Value="Test3">` is invalid because it doesn't have a name, just two attributes (Key and Value) and also it's not closed (Nodes need to either have a closing tag like `<add></add>` or be self-closing like `<add />` (Notice the / before the `>`)

Read up on the difference between a Node or Element and an Attribute in XML and it should become relatively clear what you need to build, then we can address the how.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not a solution

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It's too long to be a comment :/

Comment: Agree, but technically that's still a comment :)

Comment: I think it's a valid post, if only because @MichaelStum is pointing out which parts of the code need working on.

Comment: Agreed. I do not have enough rep to vote up or I would have. Thanks @MichaelStum